# нужно ли тире перед это?

Tags: пунктуация

Для «незалежной» гордости это, как серпом по больному месту.

Comment: Тут и запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

**Возможны оба варианта:**

**(1) Нет тире:** Для «незалежной» гордости это как серпОм по больному месту.

Нет паузы перед местоимением "это", смысловым центром является оборот, поэтому тире перед "это" не ставится.

**(2) Тире ставится:** Для «незалЕжной» гордости ―  это как серпОм по больному месту.

Авторское обособление с помощью тире, логическим ударением выделена первая часть.

Comment: См. вопрос **flossyU**: _нужно ли тире **перед** это?_

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрела, перед "это" тире возможно в качестве авторского знака, но можно обойтись и без него.

Comment: @Sibylla, по-моему, интонационное ударение подает на "гордость" : Для «незалежной» гОрдости (―) это как серпом по больному месту. Полагаю, тире нужно ставить и в этом случае. Согласны?

Comment: @Sibylla, очень интересно! Не помните, откуда информация?